# FTP Spring Integration with Inbound Streaming Channel Adapter

Tags: ftp, spring-integration-sftp

I am using spring-integration with ftp. When i use `int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter`, then it is working fine, but `int-ftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter` yields the following error:

`cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-ftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter`

What could I be missing?

The relevant portion of my code is

```
<int-ftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
         channel="ftpChannel"
         session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
         filename-pattern="*.txt"
         filename-regex=".*\.txt"
         filter="customFilter"
         remote-file-separator="/"
         comparator="comparator"
         remote-directory-expression="'/OUT/SDI402_CARATT_JD'">
     <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" />
 </int-ftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: I have cleaned up the question, but a sample of your code will be very useful in answering your question.

Comment: I fixed the code tags, for code use four spaces. You were adding spoiler tags :)

Comment: did you ever resolve this? if so what was the solution?

Comment: i  used version 4.3.7.RELEASE of spring-integration-ftp. then it start working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use in your dependencies spring integration 4.3.1.RELEASE. That solved the exact same problem in my case.

Comment: i am using the following pom entry but still i am getting the error.    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: in xml, i am using the following URL
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp/spring-integration-ftp.xsd. i didnt see any folder with ftp name, may be because of this we are getting error